# TypeConverter cannot convert from System.String nintex workflow for sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, nintex-workflow

I tried to initialize a collection variable in Nintex workflow

I set the value to

```
[{"Rating":""}]
```

When I publish the workflow I get the below error

> TypeConverter cannot convert from System.String

Is the format incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

The above value is valid json not string so if you want to use this value as string then use below

```
[{\"Rating\":\"\"}]
```